# HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync not working in Blazor

Tags: c#, rest, blazor

I have created a new project/solution using the Blazor WebAssembly App Template in Visual Studio.

Then added this Rest Api method to the existing WeatherForecastController class:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Post(string str)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

Then I tried to call it from a Blazor page:

```
@inject HttpClient Http
...
    private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("WeatherForecast"); // this works

        var reply = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("WeatherForecast", "test the west"); // this returns 400 Bad Request
    }
```

The same bad request happens when trying it with HTTPPut.

I have tried first with my own applications (which is also build upon the same template).
Tried it with HttpClient.PostAsync also. The same error here.

Comment: Are these completely separate solutions? Are you hosting them both? The code must be built and running to be able to access these endpoints

Comment: @Roe: the `[HttpGet]` already works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convention asp.net expects this parameter to be passed in the URL.

Add `[FromBody]` to the endpoint:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody]string str)
  {
      return Ok();
  }
```

Comment: Isn't there default middleware that handle this? I for example am able to send a parameter as either a queryParam or body, as long as the names match up this shouldn't be the cause. On top of that the request itself should not a bad request, only the `str` param would have no value.

Comment: It's a validation error. You will get `str==null` with `string? str` (and no FromBody).   Not sure if and how the middleware handles body/query leniancy.

Comment: Yes that works! I thought I tried this also but apparently I didn't. Thanks!

Comment: I just tested this out, you are correct. Seems that `[ApiController]` enforces the correct mapping of sent data. Since OP isn't using the `str` parameter I suggest removing it all together. And only add it if its being used.